# Installing a Python package using visual C++ for python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install the python 2.7 package primer3-py using

pip install primer3-py

in Windows 10. However, I am getting the following error:

```
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1884) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1885) : error C2065: 'SH' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1885) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'double *'
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1886) : error C2065: 'SH' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1886) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1887) : error C2065: 'SH' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1887) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1948) : error C2065: 'SH' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1948) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'double *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1948) : warning C4024: 'RSH' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1949) : error C2065: 'SH' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1949) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1949) : error C2065: 'SH' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1949) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1950) : error C2065: 'SH' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1950) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1950) : error C2065: 'SH' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1950) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1955) : error C2065: 'SH' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\alaksh\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-otgqae\primer3-py\primer3\src\libprimer3\thal.c(1955) : warning C4022: 'free' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
error: command 'C:\\Users\\Alaksh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Can someone help me out with the installation?

Comment: Have you installed cython module which is basic requirement for primer3-py.

Comment: Yeah. I have cython installed.